# Optimize mysql query with bit(12) field

Tags: mysql

I have a huge mysql table where each record is a trip.
Now I have to add information to each trip to say in which months the trip will start.

The first idea was to use a bit(12) field where each bit represents a month.

But when I query the table to find the trips for certain months, the queries are very slow because the whole table must be analyzed by doing a "bitwise and" (&) between the bit(12) field and the mask of the months.

select * when (months & b'100100000000') > 0

Is it a better solution to use 12 boolean fields (one per month) putting in the where condition some or?

select * from table when (jan=1) or (apr=1)

And can a field index on single months help in this case?

Are there any better solutions to optimize query execution time when I want to find all the trips that depart in certain months?

Comment: Why not create another table `trip_starts` with `trip_id` and starting month/date? You will get much better performance than from the bit-field and it is the correct way of doing things.

Comment: Actually I don't need the exact departure date, but just in wich month the travel will start.
So, you suggest a detail table with two field, trip_id and departure month (integer from 1 to 12).
How should I query the two tables to get all trips departing in January or April?
And what indexes should I create to optimize it?

Comment: Check EXPLAIN doesn't optimize it already. Alternately you can also `SELECT ... WHERE month_no =1  UNION ALL SELECT .... WHERE month_no = 4`.

Comment: "The first idea was to use a bit(12) field where each bit represents a month": why? This would be ideal if you could have multiple start months. Otherwise you only need 4 bits to represent 1..12, and a proper index on that column, rather than requiring a full table scan.

Comment: Each trip can start in multiple months

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question from the comments.

If you just want to keep the starting month and do not care about the year, you can use table:

```
create table trip_starts (
trip_id int,
month_number int,
primary key (month_number, trip_id)
)
```

To query the trips that start in January or April you can do:

```
select t.* 
from trips t
  join trip_starts ts on ts.trip_id=t.id
where ts.month_number in (1,4)
```

Comment: I tried the approach with a detail table for months as you suggested, but in terms of performance I didn't see any improvement compared to a solution with a boolean field for each month.
I agree that your solution is the standard solution for defining the starting dates, but since I only have to define months, independent of the year, I was hoping to find a more efficient solution.
Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: For performance questions, please include the table definitions and output of the EXPLAIN commmand for the query.

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely used 12 boolean fields. Not only speed but also further maintenance of code will get much better. You can play with indexing to see if it speeds your queries up. I suppose indexing months will not change the performance considerably. Also remember to backup your table data before you change structure of your table.